# Eclipse standard warning/error overlay icons

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, icons

I'm writing an Eclipse plug-in... In my custom label decorator, I want to overlay a warning icon, and I'd like to use the standard one used by eclipse (the little yellow triangle). How can I get an image descriptor of this icon?

I tried using

```
workbench.getSharedImages().getImageDescriptor(ISharedImages.IMG_DEC_FIELD_WARNING)
```

since that ID seems to match what I'm looking for, but the shared images collection doesn't actually have that image in it (so I just get a null returned).

Is there some other shared image collection that I should be looking at?

Comment: Update 7 years later: This should no longer be an issue since [bug 304397](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=304397) has been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have run across an Eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=304397

The bugzilla entry gives this code as workaround:

`ImageDescriptor descriptor =
JFaceResources.getImageRegistry().getDescriptor("org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.IMG_DEC_FIELD_WARNING");`